# Buildroot tools - adding a user libs from .RPM

Tags: linux, embedded, buildroot

I have some task to make linux's bootable image with my own package. This package (named **starlet**) is a set of .C modules + Makefile. I created the `package/starlet` directory and added Config.in and starlet.mk; selected in the Buildroot configuration to include my package to build target image.

So, it's works fine...

Now i'm need to build starlet's image with additional library from the **zztop-dev** package.
**zztop-dev** package is an .RPM package with set of .H and .C files to build target zztop.a (.so) libraries.

What do I need to do to install zztop-dev.RPM before building STARLET image?

Comment: What is zztop-dev? Is it publicly available on the Internet? Then please add the URL where it can be found.

Comment: So you have an .rpm file containing the sources to build this `zztop-dev` library? It's uncommon, do you have access to the original source on a .tar.gz file, a git/svn repository or anywhere else?

Answer (score 2):

Having the source code for a package stored in a `.rpm` file is quite uncommon. Buildroot has built-in rules to extract all the most common formats. Using an uncommon format requires you to write extraction rules on your own.

So the first question is whether you can use a more common format that Buildroot has rules for. You probably can access the source code from its original location in a source code repository (git, Subversion, whatever) or a tarball.

If you *really* need to extract the sources from am `.rpm` file, then you need to write your own custom extract commands. Look for LIBFOO_EXTRACT_CMDS in [the Buildroot user manual](http://nightly.buildroot.org/manual.html#_infrastructure_for_packages_with_specific_build_systems).

But if your extract commands call the `rpm` command to do the extraction then you'll need the `rpm` tool either installed on your host machine, or packaged as a host package in Buildroot and listed as a dependency of zztop-dev. The former approach is way simpler, but it will force you to have `rpm` installed on every host machine where you run the build.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Common or uncommon is not mater of the situation. I have RPM package (zztop-dev is a example of non-existent package) and i'm need to use libraries from this package at time of building the target binaries (it's other package).

Comment: @RuslanR.Laishev: Well, being uncommon matters because Buildroot has built-in rules to extract all *common* formats. Using an uncommon format requires you to write extraction rules on your own. I edited the answer to clarify that.  I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: RPM is not common ?

Comment: RPM is common as a package manager, a system used in distributions. It is not common at all as a format for open source developers to release their source code. Build systems such as Buildroot fetch the source code from the "upstream" locations, where it is distributed as a tarball, a git/svn/hg repo, sometimes a zip file and a few other formats. Distributions fetch the upstream code from the same locations and possibly re-release it as an rpm/dpkg file, but that is a by-product. Build systems have no reason to fetch a by-product when they can fetch the source at its, well, source.

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, you need to write your own custom extract commands.